# Unable to set array index at 0th position in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is a simple js code :

```js
let day = 10;

let arrayMinutes = Array(day);
const d = new Date();
d.setHours(0);
d.setMinutes(1);
d.setSeconds(0);
arrayMinutes[0] = d;
console.log("arrayMinutes[0]", d, arrayMinutes[0], arrayMinutes);

const d2 = new Date();
d2.setHours(0);
d2.setMinutes(day);
d2.setSeconds(0);
arrayMinutes[day - 1] = d2;
console.log("arrayMinutes[day]", arrayMinutes[0], arrayMinutes[day - 1], arrayMinutes);
```

And the console logs :

[image]

Why arrayMinutes[0] evaluates to 0?
According to me it should be equal to d.

Comment: What's `day` in your first line of code?

Comment: Setting `day` to `10`, I don't get 0 at all, it logs a Date as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/cs0mnkfq/

Comment: day is not defined. What is ```    arrayMinutes[day - 1] = d2;``` ???
and I suggest to use: ```      let arrayMinutes = []; ```

Comment: Assuming `day` is a number, I've updated your question to show a runnable snippet. It doesn't produce the output you've said you're getting. Please update the snippet to replicate the problem you describe, so we can help you with it.

Comment: It's an extract : day is initialized to 10 outside the function.

Comment: @Lbro - If `day` is `10`, the code doesn't do what you've said it does. Please update the snippet to accurately reflect what you're seeing.

Comment: The only code which were not in the snippet were the initialization of var day to 10 `const day=10`, outside the function.

Comment: I think I understood : the array is returned (`return arrayMinutes`) at the end of the function. And the function (called`initX`) is used to initialize a var, which, I suspect, is modified after. So returning the array is like returning a pointer, and therefore if afterward the data pointed are modified, the console.log shows the modified data. My suspiscions are correct to javascript gurus ?

Comment: @Lbro - Yes, arrays are objects, and like all objects they're referenced via object references (which are a bit like pointers).

Answer (score 2):

Beware using the `Array` constructor. My guess is that your `day` variable at the beginning of the code is a number. When you do `Array(number)`, it creates an array with no entries in it and a `length` matching that number:

```js
const a = Array(10);
console.log(a.length); // 10
console.log(a[0]);     // undefined
console.log(0 in a);   // false
```

In fact, doing that is almost the only time the `Array` constructor is useful. Any other time, use an array literal:

```js
const a = [10];
console.log(a.length); // 1
console.log(a[0]);     // 10
console.log(0 in a);   // true
```

---

The reason I say "beware" is that `Array` behaves differently based on what you give it:

1. If you give it a single number argument, as above, it creates an empty array with `length` set to that number.
2. If you give it a single non-number argument, it creates an array containing that value (with `length = 1`).
3. If you give it more than one argument, it creates an array containing those values (even if the first one is a number).

This...changing...behavior is why you should avoid the `Array` constructor entirely unless you're intentionally creating an empty array of a specified `length` (usually just prior to `fill`ing it).

Comment: That said, you've said that `arrayMinutes[0]` is `0`, not a date. I can't make that happen with your code.

Comment: This is strange. The all purpose of this function is to initialize an array so that the first item is the first minute of the current day and the last item is the last minute of the current day. (As it were not working,I tried with 10 instead of 1440). The console.log shows the first item to stay at 0, instead of being the first minute of the current day.

Answer (score 2):

The `Array()` constructor can be used in two ways:

- `Array(el0, el1, el2, ...)`

Creates an array containing `el0`, `el1`, `el2`, .... This is equivalent to `[el0, el1, el2, ...]`

- `Array(count)`

Creates an array with `count` elements, but the elements are uninitialized

If there's a single argument and it's an integer, it's taken to be the second form. So if `day` is an integer, you're creating an uninitialized array containing `day` elements.

Don't use `Array(day)`, use `[day]` to create an array just containing the value `day`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try with `push`

```js
arrayMinutes.push(d);
```